# Get the nearest date when no row matches exactly

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get data from the last weekday of the last twelve months out of my DB. It's a database that holds fund valuations which comes from an API. Each valuation has a date associated to it, which also means that there is no data on bank holidays.

The query I've been trying (I generate the query from PHP) looks like this:

```
SELECT date, kurs FROM navkurser
        WHERE
        isin = 'SE0008373951' AND date = '2019-10-30' OR
        isin = 'SE0008373951' AND date = '2020-04-29' OR
        isin = 'SE0008373951' AND date = '2020-05-29'
        etc...
```

I'm not very experienced with SQL so there's probably a more efficient way to do this query in general...

Now, this works just fine, except when there is no matching row. In this example, `2020-05-29` doesn't have any data because it was a bank holiday here. When this happens, I need to fetch the day before that instead. And if that doesn't match any data, I need to get the day before that, and so on...

So I guess the question is, how do I get the matching row closest (but not exceeding) a certain date, if it doesn't match the supplied date precisely?

Example data:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| date (DATE)   | isin (VARCHAR(50))    | kurs (FLOAT)      |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 2019-10-30    | SE0008373951          | 104.746           |
| 2020-04-29    | SE0008373951          | 100.106           |
| 2020-05-28    | SE0008373951          | 109.650           |
| 2020-06-04    | SE0008373951          | 110.650           |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you need to do "next nearest day", why not `ORDER BY day` and add a `WHERE DATE <` or` >` where necessary to do any restricting?  And you can tack on `LIMIT 1` to get only 1 record.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Are you suggesting I didn't provide a good enough dataset?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the linked answer is unsatisfactory?

Comment: @Strawberry I must be missing something. You've linked to a meta question that doesn't seem related at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery that returns the max existing date that is before or equal to the date that you want:

```
SELECT date, kurs FROM navkurser
WHERE
  isin = 'SE0008373951' AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM navkurser WHERE date <= '2019-10-30') OR
  isin = 'SE0008373951' AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM navkurser WHERE date <= '2020-04-29') OR
  isin = 'SE0008373951' AND date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM navkurser WHERE date <= '2020-05-29')
```

or:

```
SELECT date, kurs FROM navkurser
WHERE
  isin = 'SE0008373951' 
  AND date IN (
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM navkurser WHERE date <= '2019-10-30'),
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM navkurser WHERE date <= '2020-04-29'),
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM navkurser WHERE date <= '2020-05-29')
  )
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Thanks! I was not aware of how the MAX() function worked until now.